# javascript: array.push works the first time, subsequent call errors with "array.push is not a function"

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I'm having a problem getting .push to add an additional value to an array on any push beyond the first.

```
var player_score = [];

function updatePlayerScore(x) {
    player_score.push(x);
    console.log(player_score);
}
```

The first time I call `updatePlayerScore(x)` with a value of `2`, the array is successfully updated with [2] and displays in the console.

The next time I call `updatePlayerScore(x)` with any value (i.e. 4) an error is thrown *"Uncaught TypeError: player_score.push is not a function"*

Comment: It's most likely correct, in that `.push()` is not a function. Is there changing the reference of `player_score`?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Thank you for the direction - there was a change of reference to player_score in a seperate function that was causing the issue. I was able to comment out the line of code and the push worked correctly.

Comment: Just a wild guess but maybe the problem is that `player_score.push` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely working fine unless you have changed the `player_score` reference between two calls. Please check your code for usage of `player_score` variable.

```js
var player_score = [];

function updatePlayerScore(x) {
    player_score.push(x);
    console.log(player_score);
}
updatePlayerScore(2);
updatePlayerScore(4);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - I was able to find the issue further down in another function.